# Divide web page into several section and responsive

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I try to divide webpage into several sections. like header, navbar, footer, sidebar and content but i face issue when doing this.

first thing is i wants margin 10px in body and wants full width.
header is fixed-top and navbar height is not fixed because it size may be re-size in future, according to that sidebar and content is shift to bottom and also margin is 10px. footer is always bottom even if no content.

i add one checkbox for hide sidebar but unfortunately i can't added transition on it and when i move checkbox to navbar then its wont work.

in this is code i cant maintained all the things. please help me. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqLrazo8/1/)

### index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>My Header</h2>
            <h2>My Header</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <h2>My Navbar</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <input id="slide-sidebar" type="checkbox" role="button" />
            <label for="slide-sidebar"><span>close</span></label>
            <div class="sidebar-left">
                <h2>Lecture Dates</h2>
                <p>11/07 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/08 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/09 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/10 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/11 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/07 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/08 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/09 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/10 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/11 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/07 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
                <h2>Hello World</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <h3>My Footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### styles.css

```
 body {
        background-color: #9c9f84;
        margin: 0px;
        font-family: Georgia;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #header {
        background-color: #5c755e;
        margin: 10px;
        /*    height: 90px;*/
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #header h2 {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #footer {
        background-color: #5c755e;
        margin: 10px;
        bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 110%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #footer h3 {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #navbar {
        background-color: #5c755e;
        margin: 10px;
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #navbar h2 {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .portfolio {
        background-color: #e5e4d7;
        margin-left: 320px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 110%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-transition: left 1s ease;
        transition: left 1s ease;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .sidebar-left {
        background-color: #e5e4d7;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 105%;
        /*    float: left;*/
        width: 260px;
        clear: both;
        position: absolute;
        -moz-transition: left 1s ease;
        transition: left 1s ease;
    }
    input:checked ~ .portfolio {
        margin-left: 10px;
        -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
        transition: left 0.5s ease;
    }
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your English, but is this close to what you're trying to accomplish? https://jsfiddle.net/fqLrazo8/2/

Comment: thanks a lote sir, but here footer is fixed to bottom even if more content in contetnt-wrapper class.

Comment: Closer? https://jsfiddle.net/fqLrazo8/3/

Comment: when we check checkbox footer goes down.. please check

Comment: You may want to specify an animation with @keyframes instead of the transition property. It gives more control. Anyhow, https://jsfiddle.net/fqLrazo8/4/

Comment: Thank you @user2867288, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transitions weren't complete, try this CSS:

```css
body {
    background-color: #9c9f84;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#header {
    background-color: #5c755e;
    margin: 10px;
    /*    height: 90px;*/
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#header h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #5c755e;
    margin: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 110%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
#footer h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
#navbar {
    background-color: #5c755e;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#navbar h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.portfolio {
    background-color: #e5e4d7;
    /* margin-left: 320px; */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 110%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-transition: left 1s ease;
    transition: left 1s ease;
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
}
.sidebar-left {
    background-color: #e5e4d7;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 105%;
    /*    float: left;*/
    width: 260px;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    -moz-transition: left 1s ease;
    transition: left 1s ease;
}

input:checked ~ .portfolio {
    margin-left: 10px; 
    left: 0;
}

input:checked ~ .sidebar-left {
    margin-left: 10px; 
    left: -999em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>My Header</h2>
            <h2>My Header</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar">
            <h2>My Navbar</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <input id="slide-sidebar" type="checkbox" role="button" />
            <label for="slide-sidebar"><span>close</span></label>
            <div class="sidebar-left">
                <h2>Lecture Dates</h2>
                <p>11/07 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/08 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/09 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/10 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/11 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/07 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/08 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/09 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/10 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/11 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
                <p>11/07 - Lecture on Caesar</p>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio">

                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
                <h2>Hello World</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque viverra mauris nec sem condimentum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt non nulla in ullamcorper. Nulla lacinia, magna ac iaculis sodales, elit odio sagittis nisl, vel egestas sem quam sit amet leo. Maecenas pellentesque porta cursus. In ornare, diam eget maximus fermentum, felis lacus bibendum nunc, aliquam egestas dui ligula ut ante.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <h3>My Footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you sir, but in these demo footer is not set to end of the page and also width is not set (like header). if you have idea then help me